# Cannot convert value type... when using generics and polymorphism in Swift 3

Tags: swift

In my simplified example I'm getting the error: `Cannot convert value of type 'Foo' to expected argument type BaseItem<Any>`

But the class `Foo` extends `BaseItem<String>`.

This is the example code:

```
class BaseItem<T> {
    var param: T?
}

class Foo: BaseItem<Int> {
}

func checkItem(item: BaseItem<Any>) -> Bool{
    return item.param  != nil;
}
```

I get the error when calling

```
checkItem(item: Foo())
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your `checkItem` function in terms of generics too:

```
func checkItem<T>(item: BaseItem<T>) -> Bool {
    return item.param != nil
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `checkItem` function should be: `checkItem<T>(item: BaseItem<T>) -> Bool`, as follows:

```
func checkItem<T>(item: BaseItem<T>) -> Bool {
    return item.param  != nil
}
```

Usage:

```
checkItem(item: Foo()) // false

let myFoo = Foo()
myFoo.param = 0

checkItem(item: myFoo) // true
```

The reason of why the compiler complains about

> Cannot convert value of type 'Foo' to expected argument type
>   BaseItem

is that you are trying to pass `BaseItem<Int>` instance as `BaseItem<Any>` which is invalid (`Any` data type is *not* `T` generic type).

Answer (score 0):

Gotta define checkItem function with generics too.

```
func checkItem<T>(item: BaseItem<T>) -> Bool {
     return item.param  != nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [generics are invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41976844/2976878) – consider if your `checkItem(item:)` function had said:

```
func checkItem(item: BaseItem<Any>) {
    item.param = "foo"
}
```

That would be illegal for a `BaseItem<Int>`, as you cannot possibly assign a `String` instance to an `Int?` property – which is why it (an instance of `Foo`) cannot be typed as a `BaseItem<Any>`.

The solution, as other answers have said, is to use a generic placeholder for the function:

```
func checkItem<T>(item: BaseItem<T>) -> Bool {
    return item.param != nil
}
```

Now, rather than saying that you're taking a `BaseItem<Any>`, that has a `param` of type `Any?` (can be assigned a value of *any* type) – you're now saying that you're taking a `BaseItem` with any *specific* placeholder type; which will be satisfied at the call-site of the function.

The function implementation itself therefore cannot make any assumptions about this type, and will disallow the assignment of an arbitrary value to `param`. The compiler will only allow an assignment of a value of type `T`.