# Swift generic enum as a parameter for escaping closure that is a parameter for function

Tags: ios, swift, generics, enums, type-inference

```
protocol A {}
extension Int: A {}
extension String: A {}

enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case error(Error)
}

typealias BaseFunc = (Result<A>) -> ()

func foo(r: Result<Int>) {}
func bar(r: Result<String>) {}

var f: BaseFunc = foo
```

Compiler says `cannot convert value of type '(Result<Int>) -> ()' to specified type 'BaseFunc' (aka '(Result<A>) -> ()')`

Is what I'm trying to do possible in Swift? Maybe there is another way to achieve similar result?

@iWheelBuy answered correctly for this question. However I formulated it wrong. What I want is something like this:

```
protocol A {}
extension Int: A {}
extension String: A {}

enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case error(Error)
}

typealias BaseFunc<T> = (Result<T>) -> ()

func foo(r: Result<Int>) {}
func bar(r: Result<String>) {}

var f: BaseFunc<A>
if arc4random_uniform(10) < 5 {
    f = foo
} else {
    f = bar
}
```

Which results in: `cannot assign value of type '(Result<Int>) -> ()' to type '(Result<A>) -> ()'`

Comment: A `(Result<Int>) -> Void` is not a `(Result<A>) -> Void`. Say your code complied; I could say `f(.success("foobar"))`. We just passed a `String` to something expecting an `Int`. But in any case, [generics are invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41976844/2976878), so the opposite would be just as illegal (but is technically sound because of the value semantics of `Result`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this way?

```
typealias BaseFunc<B:A> = (Result<B>) -> ()
```

Your `typealias` doesn't have a generic parameter

Comment: You are absolutely correct. However when I tried to follow your advice in my more specific example it still fails.
    protocol A {}
    extension Int: A {}
    extension String: A {}
    
    enum Result<T> {
        case success(T)
        case error(Error)
    }
    
    typealias BaseFunc<T> = (Result<T>) -> ()
        
    func foo(r: Result<Int>) {}
    func bar(r: Result<String>) {}
    
    var f: BaseFunc<A>
    if arc4random_uniform(10) < 5 {
        f = foo
    } else {
        f = bar
    }

Comment: @SergeRykovski [My comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997818/swift-generic-enum-as-a-parameter-for-escaping-closure-that-is-a-parameter-for-f#comment78957302_45997818) still applies to your new example. A `(Result<Int>) -> ()` is *not* a `(Result<A>) -> Void`.

Comment: @SergeRykovski can you please also tell us the way you want to use VAR F after it is set?

Comment: @iWheelBuy In real life scenario there is a bunch of functions with similar signatures - the only difference between that is the actual class that is wrapped in Result (all of those classes conform to A). There's an API that returns Result<A> (I don't always know actual class that's wrapped in result, however I intend to use only in context of conformance to A). So following functional style I'd like to have a function that returns function (depending on some rules). I have an API that returns Result<A> (depending on some other rules). In the end I want to call returned function with result.