# Swift (4) cannot cast to generic base class?

Tags: swift, generics, swift4

In Swift, if I declare a class based on generic type:

```
class BasicRequest<T>{
}

class StartRequest: BasicRequest<BasicPayload> {
}
```

And then try to use generic method:

```
class SocketClient {

  public func send(request: BasicRequest<Any>){
  }
}
```

It does not compile:

```
SocketClient.shared.send(request: StartRequest())
```

with message

> Cannot convert value of type 'StartRequest' to expected argument
>   type 'BasicRequest'

Why actually? The type info should be available across the inheritance chain.

Comment: ReconnectRequest/AbstractWebSocketMessage from the error message are nowhere defined in your code. Please post the *real* code/message.

Comment: `Any` has nothing to do with generics.

Comment: Sorry, corrected text

Comment: send(request: BasicRequest<T>) does not compile either

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Swift generic coercion misunderstanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976844/swift-generic-coercion-misunderstanding): `BasicRequest<Any>` and `BasicRequest<BasicPayload>` are different, unrelated types.

Comment: can you provide Basic PAy Load

Comment: @ArnieSchwarzvogel, it's `func send<T>(request: BasicRequest<T>)`, you forgot to declare generic parameter.

Comment: Recurring question, generics are invariant in Swift, this is why your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Generics are invariant in Swift, which in your case means that `BasicRequest<Any>` is not compatible with `BasicRequest<BasicPayload>`, even if `BasicPayload` is compatible with `Any`. This is how invariants work, there's little you can do in this direction.

What you can do, is to make `send` generic, thus allowing any kind of `BasicRequest` instances to be passed:

```
public func send<T>(request: BasicRequest<T>){
}
```