# Append generic struct to an array

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, promisekit

I have an array of a generic Struct, the generic type of the struct extends of the class `ResponseBase`. In the function I try to append to the `responseMapping` array but no luck there, it always has the following error: `Error: Cannot convert value of type 'ResponseMap<ResponseType>' to expected argument type 'ResponseMap<ResponseBase>'`. I already tried to add the Any, AnyClass, AnyObject or whatever Any as the Type but it also didn't really work out.

I tried to do it with Type Erasure but I got confused and I gave up. Anyone knows how to do this correctly?

**Code**

```swift
struct ResponseMap<ResponseType: ResponseBase> {
    var fulfill: (ResponseType) -> ()
}

public class MessengerTest {
    var responseMapping = [ResponseMap]()

    func send<ResponseType, Type>(_ message: Type) -> Promise<ResponseType> where ResponseType: ResponseBase, Type: Base<ResponseType> {
        return Promise<ResponseType> { resolver in
            let map = ResponseMap(fulfill: resolver.fulfill)
            self.responseMapping.append(map)       <---- Error
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**
This is code which throws the same Error, but without PromiseKit.

```swift
class Promise<U> {
  let fulfill: (U)->Void

  init() {
    fulfill = {U in
      print("fulfill")
    }
  }
}

class Base {

}

class Response: Base {

}

class Response1: Base {

}

struct ResponseMap<U: Base> {
  let fulfill: (U)->Void
}


var responseMapping = [ResponseMap]()

let promise1 = Promise<Response>()
let promise2 = Promise<Response1>()

let map1 = ResponseMap(fulfill: promise1.fulfill)
let map2 = ResponseMap(fulfill: promise2.fulfill)

responseMapping.append(map1)
responseMapping.append(map2)
```

Comment: When you declare your method `func send<ResponseType, Type>` `ResponseType` is just a generic type as well as `Type`. You should use any single letter, usually  `T`, in this case <T,U> to represent your newly created types. They have no relationship the one you used here `struct ResponseMap<ResponseType: ResponseBase> {`.

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes this is true, but it will not change the Error, it will only change the naming of the Types....

Comment: I never said it would. Just for you to realize what you are actually doing. `func send<ResponseType, Type>(_ message: Type)` is the same as `func send<T, U>(_ message: U)`

Comment: @LeoDabus okay thx, any idea on how to fix the issue?

Comment: @LeoDabus, I added some code which throws the same error, but without the promisekit. I would really appreciate it if you could have a look :)

Comment: try `Promise<Base>` instead of `Promise<Response>` or change your struct declaration to `struct ResponseMap<U: Response> {`

Comment: @LeoDabus, okay yes in this case you are right. But in my case, I will have multiple classes extending from Base, so I try to append all classes extending from Base into the array.

Comment: This is due to generics being invariant in Swift, this is why you cannot append to the array. There are many SO questions on this topic, a good one is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976844/swift-generic-coercion-misunderstanding