# Can I create an array of semi heterogenous generic objects in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, protocols

I’d like to create an array of different objects of the same generic class:

```swift
import UIKit
struct S<V: UIView> {}
let a: [S<UIView>] = [S<UIButton>(), S<UILabel>()]
```

> `Cannot convert value of type 'S<UIButton>' to expected element type 'S<UIView>'`
>   `Cannot convert value of type 'S<UILabel>' to expected element type 'S<UIView>'`

The only workaround I could come up with is a protocol wrapper:

```swift
import UIKit
protocol P {}
struct S<V: UIView>: P {}
let a: [P] = [S<UIButton>(), S<UILabel>()]
```

I don’t really feel like it is necessary to redefine all of `S`’s properties and methods in `P`. Are there any other solutions out there?

**EDIT:**

With this workaround one would also run into the problem of needing a assotiated type in the protocol:

```swift
import UIKit
protocol P {
    associatedtype V: UIView
}
struct S<V: UIView>: P {}
let a: [P] = [S<UIButton>(), S<UILabel>()]
```

> `Protocol 'P' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

How would I solve this?

Comment: This is caused by the fact that [generic types in Swift are invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976844/swift-generic-coercion-misunderstanding). This means that `S<UIButton>` and `S<UIView>` are completely unrelated types. Why do you need `S` to be generic? Couldn't you simply use the base-class, `UIView` for your generic parameters/properties in `S` instead?

Comment: I see. Interesting post. Thank you. I can’t use `UIView` if I want to store properties; these don’t go into extensions.