# Convert concrete type having generic in class signature swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, codable

I have a `struct` like this

```
struct ApiResponse<T: Codable>: Codable {
 let result: T?
 let statusCode: String?
}
```

Somewhere in my code I need `statusCode`. I am not interested in `result` but Swift is not allowing me to use following:

```
let apiResponse = value as? ApiResponse
```

it shows following error:

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred in cast to 'ApiResponse'

which is quite obvious since struct definition ask some struct conforming to `Codable` but at same time i can not use one type as it will fail for other types.

e.g.

```
let apiResponse = value as? ApiResponse<ApiResult>
```

would be true for one type of response but if i have `ApiResponse<ApiOtherResult>` it will fail.

```
        NetworkLayer.requestObject(router: router) { (result: NetworkResult<T>) in

        switch result {
        case .success(let value):
            if let apiResponse = value as? ApiResponse {
                }
        case .failure: break
        }

    }
```

Comment: Check [Swift generic coercion misunderstanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976844/swift-generic-coercion-misunderstanding). There's no such type as `ApiResponse` and `ApiResponse<A> and `ApiResponse<B>` are completely unrelated types even if `A` and `B` are related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest adding a new protocol

```
protocol StatusCodeProvider {
    var statusCode: String? { get }
}
```

Add it as a requirement in your function making sure that `T` in `NetworkResult<T>` conforms to `StatusCodeProvider` and add conformance for every `T` you want to request.