# Casting a generic class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics

I have a class of the following type:

```swift
class OptionViewModel<T: SelectableOption>: ViewModel
```

At some other point I need to be able to do something like the following:

```swift
func configure(viewModel: ViewModel) {
  guard let model = model as? OptionViewModel else { return }
}
```

I don't care at this point what the generic type is (only that it conforms to the protocol) but I can't get this line to compile due to having to supply a concrete type here (which I don't know - currently I have 4 possibilities).

`Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred in cast to 'OptionViewModel'`

I'm looking for any suggestions on how to restructure this, or get around my issue.  Thanks!

Comment: "I don't care at this point what the generic type is (only that it conforms to the protocol)" I'm not sure what protocol you are talking about here. `OptionViewModel` is not a protocol. Do you want to check for `ViewModel` instead (which presumably is a protocol)?

Comment: "currently I have 4 possibilities" - this is the problem. The compiler doesn't know which one you mean either `OptionViewModel<A>` and `OptionViewModel<B>` are unrelated types as far as the compiler is concerned. Even thought they are both specialisations off the same generic type they are not related in the way superclass/subclasses are. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976844/swift-generic-coercion-misunderstanding and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62285398/convert-concrete-type-having-generic-in-class-signature-swift