# Use Type Erasure return Generic Type in a function with Swift (Cannot convert return expression of type…)

Tags: swift, generics

I have a problem with generics in swift. Let's expose my code.

```
protocol FooProtocol {
    associatedtype T
}

protocol Fooable { }
extension Int : Fooable { }
extension String: Fooable { }

class AnyFoo<T>: FooProtocol {
    init<P: FooProtocol>(p: P) where P.T == T { }
}

class FooIntImpClass: FooProtocol {
    typealias T = Int
}

class FooStringImpClass: FooProtocol {
    typealias T = String
}

func createOne(isInt: Bool) -> AnyFoo<Fooable> {
    if isInt {
        let anyFoo = AnyFoo(p: FooIntImpClass())
          return anyFoo
    } else {
        let anyFoo = AnyFoo(p: FooStringImpClass())
        return anyFoo
    }
}

func createTwo<F: Fooable>(isInt: Bool) -> AnyFoo<F> {
    if isInt {
        let anyFoo = AnyFoo(p: FooIntImpClass())
          return anyFoo
    } else {
        let anyFoo = AnyFoo(p: FooStringImpClass())
        return anyFoo
    }
}
```

`createOne` got an error

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyFoo' (aka 'AnyFoo') to return type 'AnyFoo'

`createTwo` got an error

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyFoo' (aka 'AnyFoo') to return type 'AnyFoo'

Why is this happening. I'm returning the correct value.

And What is the difference with the `createOne` and `createTwo`

Comment: You are not returning the correct value. You declare `createOne` to return `AnyFoo<P>`, but then you are always returning the same type, `AnyFoo<Int>`, so the function is not generic. What is it that you are actually trying to achieve with your `createOne` function?

Comment: The code has a error, change the `createOne` to following code, also has error
`func createOne() -> AnyFoo<Any> {
    let anyFoo = AnyFoo(p: FooImpClass())
    return anyFoo
}`

Comment: If you are using `Any` in a generic type, you are abusing generics very badly. That will also never work, because Swift generic types are invariant - `AnyFoo<Any>` is completely unrelated to all other `AnyFoo` types, such as `AnyFoo<Int>`, even though `Any` can be used to represent all Swift types.

Comment: I have edited my answer to respond to your edits. Note that you should not edit your question so substantially that it invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT to respond to the edit to the question:

`createTwo` doesn't work because you have the same misconception as I said in my original answer. `createTwo` decided on its own that `F` should be either `String` or `Int`, rather than "any type that conforms to `Fooable`".

For `createOne`, you have another common misconception. **Generic classes are invariant**. `AnyFoo<String>` is not a kind of `AnyFoo<Fooable>`. In fact, they are totally unrelated types! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976844/swift-generic-coercion-misunderstanding) for more details.

Basically, what you are trying to do violates type safety, and you redesign your APIs and pick another different approach.

---

Original answer (for initial revision of question)

You seem to be having a common misconception of generics. **Generic parameters are decided by the caller, not the callee.**

In `createOne`, you are returning `anyFoo`, which is of type `AnyFoo<Int>`, not `AnyFoo<P>`. The method (callee) have decided, on its own, that `P` should be `Int`. This shouldn't happen, because the *caller* decides what generic parameters should be. If the callee is generic, it must be able to work with *any* type (within constraints). Anyway, `P` can't be `Int` here anyway, since `P: FooProtocol`.

Your `createOne` method should not be generic at all, as it only works with `Int`:

```
func createOne() -> AnyFoo<Int> {
    let anyFoo = AnyFoo(p: FooImpClass())
    return anyFoo
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the following what you tried to achieve? (compiled & tested with Xcode 11.4)

```
func createOne() -> some FooProtocol {
    let anyFoo = AnyFoo(p: FooImpClass())
    return anyFoo
}
```

Comment: Nice, I always forget about opaque types

Comment: In the future I will add the type `String`, `Double`, etc。the opaque types do not support this.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
I finally managed to keep your `where clause` :)

**EDIT**
Still not sure what you want to do, and I still agree with @Sweeper but I love to badly abuse generics :) :

```
protocol FooProtocol {
    associatedtype T
    init()
}

protocol Fooable { }
extension Int : Fooable { }
extension String: Fooable { }

class AnyFoo<T>: FooProtocol {
    init<P: FooProtocol>(p: P) where P.T == T { }
    init<T>(p: T.Type) { }
    required init() { }
}

class FooIntImpClass: FooProtocol {
    typealias T = Int
    required init() { }
}

class FooStringImpClass: FooProtocol {
    typealias T = String
    required init() { }
}


func createOne<F: FooProtocol>(foo: F.Type) -> AnyFoo<F.T> {
    let anyFoo = AnyFoo<F.T>(p: F.init())
        return anyFoo
}

func createTwo<F: FooProtocol>(foo: F.Type) -> some FooProtocol {
    let anyFoo = AnyFoo<F.T>(pk: F.T.self)
    return anyFoo
}
```

that compiles but I don't know what to do with it.

**Edit**

yeah I really don't know:

```
let one = createOne(foo: FooStringImpClass.self) // AnyFoo<String>
print(type(of: one).T) // "String\n"
let two = createTwo(foo: FooIntImpClass.self) // AnyFoo<Int>
print(type(of: two).T) // "Int\n"
```

**Is that what you wanted ?**

---

I'm not sure what you want to do with that, but I suggest you try putting a `where` clause on the `AnyFoo` class instead of it's initializer.
And I should add, that your where clause on the initializer was wrong, Like [Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62406002/1425697) said :

> Anyway, P can't be Int here anyway, since P: FooProtocol.

The following code compiles :

```
protocol FooProtocol {
    associatedtype T
}

class AnyFoo<T>: FooProtocol where T: FooProtocol {
    init<P: FooProtocol>(p: P) { }
}

class FooImpClass: FooProtocol {
    typealias T = Int
}

func createOne<P: FooProtocol>() -> AnyFoo<P> {
    let anyFoo: AnyFoo<P> = AnyFoo(p: FooImpClass())
    return anyFoo
}
```