# How to use a Generic Type as the function's return type in swift

Tags: swift, generics

This is the real life code. https://gist.github.com/Terriermon/0fa20dae02fed0c39b4bfe54e7db50b8
This is new code. I think this code show the problem in my project.

```
protocol TestReturnTypeProtocol {
    associatedtype T
    func test(_ type: T)
}

protocol Testable {}

extension Int: Testable { }
extension String: Testable { }

class AnyTestReturnType<Type>: TestReturnTypeProtocol where Type: Testable {
    init<P: TestReturnTypeProtocol>(_ p: P) where P.T == Type { }
    func test(_ type: Type) { }
}

class IntReturnClass: TestReturnTypeProtocol {
    func test(_ type: Int) { }
}
class StringReturnClass: TestReturnTypeProtocol {
    func test(_ type: String) { }
}


func tesfFunction<T: Testable>(isInt: Bool) -> AnyTestReturnType<T> {
    if isInt {
        let intRet = AnyTestReturnType(IntReturnClass())
        return intRet
    } else {
        let strRet = AnyTestReturnType<String>(StringReturnClass())
        return strRet
    }
}
```

This is the code.
And I do not want to use the `as!`,Because It can not work in some cases.
 In my project ,if I use the as, It will complain `Cast from 'AnyValidatorConvertible<Int>' to unrelated type 'AnyValidatorConvertible<T>' always fails`

```
protocol TestProtocol { }
extension Int: TestProtocol { }
extension String: TestProtocol { }

class TestClass<T: TestProtocol> {
    let value: T
    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

func testFunction<T: TestProtocol>(isInt: Bool) -> TestClass<T> {
    if isInt {
        return TestClass(value: 0)
    } else {
        return TestClass(value: "")
    }
}
```

This is the error message. `Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'T'`.

Comment: The reason you're getting that error because the compiler needs to know at compile time what the type of `T` is going to be at runtime. If you run `testFunction(isInt: Bool.random())` there's no way to know if `T` will be `Int` or `String`. If you give us a real life example of what you're trying to do we might be able to figure out a better way to do it.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Terriermon/0fa20dae02fed0c39b4bfe54e7db50b8
This is the real life example. Tks

Comment: Okay, having seen your real code, if I have an array of `LoginValidatorType`, and I chose a `randomElement` from that array, and pass it to `validatorFor`. What would I get? Depending on _which_ `LoginValidatorType` I chose, I could get different types, couldn't I? And the method decides what type I get. Anyway, I'm tempting to close this as a duplicate of  [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62405675/5133585), unless you can explain how this question is different...

Comment: Yes, You will get difference types. So I want to use the protocol to hide the concrete type. I want use it  as `let validator = LoginValidatorFactory.validatorFor(type: .phone) // return the AnyValidatorConvertible<Validationable>
    validator.validated("0000000")`.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I think it should be the third case in your conditions.

```
protocol TestProtocol { }
extension Int: TestProtocol { }
extension String: TestProtocol { }

class TestClass<T: TestProtocol> {
    let value: T
    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

func testFunction<T: TestProtocol>(isInt: Bool) -> TestClass<T>? {
    if isInt, let genericInt = 0 as? T {
        return TestClass(value: genericInt)
    } else if let genericString = "" as? T {
        return TestClass(value: genericString)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: In my Project, It is complex. I can not use the `as`. If I use the `as`, It will complain `Cast from 'AnyValidatorConvertible<Int>' to unrelated type 'AnyValidatorConvertible<T>' always fails`

Answer (score 0):

Int, String and T conform to TestProtocol.
But all of three is not the same.

According to your codes,
You should put T.type into `TestCalss(value: T)` not `TestProtocol`.

So You are supposed to `cast` the argument

```
import Foundation

protocol TestProtocol { }
extension Int: TestProtocol { }
extension String: TestProtocol { }

class TestClass<T: TestProtocol> {
    let value: T
    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    static func makeTestClass(isInt: Bool) -> TestClass? {
        switch isInt {
        case true where 0 is T:
            return TestClass(value: 0 as! T)
        case false where "" is T:
            return TestClass(value: "" as! T)
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I change the code, can you help me solve the question with the new  code? Tks