# Variable of subclass inheriting superclass with generic type

Tags: ios, swift, generics, inheritance

I have a class `Superclass` with generic type `UIView`. The class `Subclass` inherits from `Superclass`:

```
class Superclass<T: UIView>: UIViewController { ... }

class Subclass: Superclass<UIButton> { ... }
```

And now, from another `UIViewController` I am trying to initialise an object of type `Subclass` like this:

```
let childViewController: Superclass<UIView>?
    switch type {
    case .typeOne:
      childViewController = Subclass()
    default:
      childViewController = nil
    }
```

But is is throwing the following error:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'Subclass' to type 'Superclass<UIView>?'
```

How can I specify that I want to initialise the `childViewController` with a `UIButton` type, for example?

Thanks!

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40139806/5555803).

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov I cannot get it working...

Comment: Even though `UIButton` is a subtype of `UIView`, `Superclass<UIButton>` is *not* a subtype of `Superclass<UIView>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an object of `Superclass`, you initiate it like,

```
    let parentViewController: Superclass<UIButton>? = Superclass<UIButton>()
```

i.e. you need to use the same `Type` for `Generic` while instantiating the object, as you have used while defining the variable.

Similarly, the Subclass is of type `Superclass<UIButton>` and not `Superclass<UIView>`.

So, you need to define `childViewController` with the same `Generic` type, that the `Subclass` accepts, i.e.

```
    let childViewController: Superclass<UIButton>?
    switch type {
    case .typeOne:
        childViewController = Subclass()
    default:
        childViewController = nil
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I already got that working, but the thing is that I have a `switch case` that depending on the value, I want to initialise that `Subclass` class with different types of `UIView`. How can I achieve that?