# Cannot assign a value of type 'AnyDataSource<NSManagedObjectSubclass>' to a value of type 'AnyDataSource<NSManagedObject>'

Tags: ios, swift, generics, core-data, type-erasure

I'm stumped.

The title of this question the compiler error.

I am creating an object that basically marries the delegates of `NSFetchedResultsController` and `UITableViewDataSource`.  The type parameter is used to indicate which `NSManagedObject` subclass should be used in the fetch requests.

Here is an example where Swift lacks dynamism and we end up writing all sorts of crazy code, (OR, I'm new to Swift and dislike being told what I'm not allowed to do)

So, on a `UITableViewController` subclass, i'd like to have a property

```
var dataSource: AnyDataSource<NSManagedObject>?
```

when I try to create one of these with a subclass of `NSManagedObject` and assign it to that property, the compiler complains.  There seems to be nothing I can do that will succeed without a warning.

You would think that I should be able to use `NSManagedObject` or any of its subclasses, so I'm a little confused.

Any ideas?  I'm using typical "type erasure" patterns that can be found on the internet, like via `realm.io`.

Comment: But what if `AnyDataSource<T>` has a method which takes an input of type `T`? If you could pass an `AnyDataSource<NSManagedObjectSubclass>` to a `AnyDataSource<NSManagedObject>`, you could pass a `NSManagedObject` to a `NSManagedObjectSubclass`, which is illegal.

Comment: Related: [How do I store a value of type Class<ClassImplementingProtocol> in a Dictionary of type \[String:Class<Protocol>\] in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38590548/2976878)

Comment: T is constrained.  where `T: NSManagedObject`, `T:NSFetchRequestResult`

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I found that this approach was not possible. I mean, to achieve these with completely protocol-based programming.

I defined a few base protocols with no associated type, implemented an abstract baseclass that implements that protocol, then introduced generic type parameters in subclasses, that implement further protocols that have associated type.

I'll post my generalized solution on github when it's finished.