# Swift cannot understand Class<String> as Class<AnyHashable>

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, swift3

Is there a good reason why this fails:

```
class Test<T: Hashable> {}

var d: Test<AnyHashable>? = nil
let t = Test<String>()
d = t // Cannot assign value of type 'Test<String>' to type 'Test<AnyHashable>?'
```

while this obviously works ?

```
var d: AnyHashable? = nil
let t = "123"
d = t // Works fine
```

Comment: Generics are invariant, therefore `Test<String>` is a completely unrelated type to `Test<AnyHashable>` – see [How do I store a value of type Class<ClassImplementingProtocol> in a Dictionary of type \[String:Class<Protocol>\] in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38590548/2976878) & [Swift generic coercion misunderstanding](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41976844/2976878)

Comment: Thanks. That's really annoying!