# In Swift, how to mock a protocol which has constrained generic functions?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, generics, mocking, protocols

I'm trying to create a mock as shown below and getting the compile warning. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Or perhaps there's a different approach in creating this mock.

```
protocol Decodable {}

struct Action<D: Decodable> {}

protocol Requestable {
    func perform<T: Decodable>(action: Action<T>)
}

class MockRequestable<U: Decodable>: Requestable {
    var action: Action<U>!

    func perform<T: Decodable>(action: Action<T>) {
        self.action = action as? Action<U> 
        // Warning: Cast from 'Action<T>' to unrelated type 'Action<U>' always fails
    }
}
```

Comment: Generics are invariant – thus a `Action<T>` is not an `Action<U>`, even if a `T` is a `U`. See [How do I store a value of type Class<ClassImplementingProtocol> in a Dictionary of type \[String:Class<Protocol>\] in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38590548/2976878) & [Swift generic coercion misunderstanding](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41976844/2976878)

Comment: Thanks for the links - after reading, it seems like the only way to do this is via Type Erasure in which case my `Action` struct and `perform` func would no longer be generic. `Action` would use the erased `AnyDecodable` - correct?

Comment: I'm not sure entirely on what you're using `action` for, but given that it's a struct, simply converting it to an `Action<U>` would work – depending on how `Action` is actually implemented. But yes, a type erasure should work too.

Comment: Thanks @Hamish - I'm clear now.