# Swift not accepting generic specialization as return type

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance

I am trying to return an specialized type `DepositItemViewModel` of `TransactionItemViewModel` but I am getting a compile error: **Cannot convert DepositItemViewModel to return type TransactionItemViewModel**.

[Cannot convert DepositItemViewModel to return type TransactionItemViewModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDnFS.png)

Here are my classes declaration:

```
class Deposit: Transaction 

class TransactionItemViewModel<T: Transaction>

class DepositItemViewModel: TransactionItemViewModel<Deposit>
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GenericParametersAndArguments.html

Comment: A `TransactionItemViewModel<Deposit>` is not a `TransactionItemViewModel<Transaction>`. Compare [Swift generic coercion misunderstanding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41976844/2976878) & [How do I store a value of type Class<ClassImplementingProtocol> in a Dictionary of type \[String:Class<Protocol>\] in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38590548/2976878)

Answer (score 0):

using protocol

```
protocol P{}
class A: P{}
class B<T: P>{}
class C:B<A>{}


func f(o: AnyObject)->B<P> {
    return C()
}
```

gives you

```
error: using 'P' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'P' is not supported
```

using class

```
class P{}
class A: P{}
class B<T: P>{}
class C:B<A>{}


func f(o: AnyObject)->B<P> {
    return C()
}
```

gives you

```
error: cannot convert return expression of type 'C' to return type 'B<P>'
```

returning type in both cases must be `B<A>`

in your case you have to change the returning type to `TransactionItemViewModel<Deposit>`