# Cannot convert generic type to generic of Any/super class

Tags: swift, xcode, generics

I'm trying to understand why i'm getting error in the following code:

```
class A <T> {}
class B {}
class C : B {}

let a = A<C>() as A<B>
```

While this line of code is working:

```
let b = C() as B
```

Comment: The key message from the linked answer is *"arbitrary generic types are invariant"*. The answer itself links to https://stackoverflow.com/a/38591285/2442804 which gives a pretty clear example why your code must not work.